# switchMap is returning one item

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, firebase, rxjs

I'm trying to switch the observable using the switchMap operator:

```
return this.db.list(`UserPlaces/${this.authData.auth.auth.currentUser.uid}`, {
    query: {
      orderByChild: 'deleted',
      equalTo: false
    }
  })
  .map((locations:any)=>{
    console.log(JSON.stringify(locations,null,2));
    return locations.map(location=>{
      return location.$key;
    });
  }).flatMap(locations=>{
    return locations
  }).switchMap(location=>{
    console.log(location);
    return this.db.object(`Devices/${location}`)
  })
  .do(console.log);
```

I'm getting one observable instead of array of observable.

> I need to get array of "this.db.object(`Devices/${location}`)"

How to solve that?

thanks.

Comment: You're flattening the array with `flatMap(locations => locations)`. Then `switchMap ` is called for each emission.

Comment: thank you for your replying,,, i reversed the switchMap and the flatMap positions and it work now, but still i have how to merge the separated object emitted by the flatMap operator,, actually any the reverse of the flatMap,, do you have any idea

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to `forkJoin` the observables to get them into one submission. You can do that like this:

```js
return this.db.list(`UserPlaces/${this.authData.auth.auth.currentUser.uid}`, {
    query: {
      orderByChild: 'deleted',
      equalTo: false
    }
  })
  .map((locations:any)=>{
    console.log(JSON.stringify(locations,null,2));
    return locations.map(location=>{
      return location.$key;
    });
  }).switchMap(locationKeys =>{
    console.log(location);
    const locationObs = locationKeys.map((key) => this.db.object(`Devices/${key}`);
    return Observable.forkJoin(...locationObs);
  })
  .reduce((acc, location) => [...acc, location], []);
  .do(console.log);
```

Comment: thank you for your reply,,what is the reverse of the flatMap ?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. Perhaps you are trying to turn each location key into a single emission from an observable? If so I woul change the first `map` to a `switchMap` and then return `Observable.of(...locations.map(location=> location.$key)` in that callback and remove the `flatMap` altogether.

Comment: forget about what i'm trying to do,, just a question,, flatMap emit separate items,, object --> object-->... what i need is reverse of flatMap that emit one item inside an array [obejct,object,...]

Comment: If your Observable is guaranteed to complete then you can use `reduce` which "applies an accumulator function over the source Observable, and returns the accumulated result when the source completes, given an optional seed value." http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-reduce